# Schedule songs as alarms that sound ONCE with no need to touch 'Dismiss' or 'Sneeze' or anything similar

Tags: alarm

I would like my Smartphone to play certain sound tracks at certain hours each day (quite similar to military-style buggle calls for waking up, assembly, lunchtime and so on). But I want the device to play the sound without asking me to confirm that I have heard it. No "Dismiss" / "Snooze" / "OK" buttom. Simply the sound at the scheduled time played once and nothing more.

Which application would do it? - Preferably a GNU program. Or any other kind of free software without advertising (it seems an odd petition, but we Linux users are used to that).

Answer (score 1):

Tasker would be a nice solution - it's not free, but it's very handy in a lot of other scenarios too.

Comment: Thanks, +1. Sorry I forgot to add that is should be a free app.

Comment: Follow up to the [tasker tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) then, which also names a few free alternatives. But though I know that "we Linux users" (pledging guilty ;) are used to "free software": I've bought *Tasker* after trying its free version for 3 days. It's worth every cent, and I've never regretted that decision (but would have regretted deciding otherwise). You don't know the powers of the dar... oops, of that app – I bet it can even make a coffee :)